# Is there a way to avoid using 'null' to show appbar actions with condition in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar

I wonder if there is a way to avoid setting null to actions if i have this state condition:

```
appBar: AppBar(
      title: provider.appBarTitle,
      actions: provider.editState == EditState.inactive
          ? [
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: provider.activateEditableState,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.edit))
            ]
          : null)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fine if you return an empty list instead of `null`.

```dart
appBar: AppBar(
  title: provider.appBarTitle,
  actions: [
    if (provider.editState == EditState.inactive)
      IconButton(
        onPressed: provider.activateEditableState,
        icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
      ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: I've tried doing that in a different way!! thanks for the reply btw. I want to avoid as much boilerplate code as I can.

Answer (score 0):

```
appBar: AppBar(
title: provider.appBarTitle,
actions:[ 
  provider.editState == EditState.inactive
  ? 
   IconButton(
   onPressed: provider.activateEditableState,
   icon: const Icon(Icons.edit))
  :
   // return a Container instead of null
   Container(),
  // other actions...
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: This is almost the same as my question, the Container is not required as well. Using an if condition as @mmcdon20 suggested, his implementation its much more clear.